# Invoke a REST Service with parameters in WSO2BPS

Tags: rest, parameters, wso2, bpel

I'm giving a try to WSO2BPS deploying BPEL processes designed in Intalio and to tell the truth I've faced a lot of problems and despite of the fact that I've could solved most of then right now I'm stucked invoking a Rest Service with parameters.

I've read a few pages about this but with not answer to my problem,

I'd like to know if someone around here has achieved it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you "wire up" the parameters that you have the process corresponding to the REST service selected. The processes each have their own namespace, and wiring the arguments in another process will not carry over.

Comment: Error sending message to Axis2 forE mex {PartnerRoleMex  calling WSAEndpoint@74a6f311.mediate(...) Status REQUEST}
    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 404 Error: Not Found
Conf

    <wsdl:binding ...>
      <http:binding verb="GET" />
      <wsdl:operation name="mediate">
       <http:operation location="getName?nombre={nombre}&amp;apellido={apellido}" /> 
       ....
      </wsdl:operation>
     </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="GetProxy">      
       <http:address location="http://localhost:8080/rest-services" />
      </wsdl:port>
     </wsdl:service>

Comment: Yes, I had this EXACT problem and error. The solution that I found was to ensure that I was "wiring up" the variable from the input message to the REST service inputs WHILE the process representing that REST service was selected.

Comment: I believe they are wired maybe namespace problem ?

Comment: Have you ever designed a process with Intalio Designer and deployed on WSO2BPS ? I'm trying to acomplish this but no success...